# Insert a JSON input into a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-workbench

I need to insert the below `JSON` into a MySQL table as below.

```
{
  "RelationshipType" : [ 
    {
        "ID" : 1,
        "FromID" : 70,
        "ToID" : 12
    },
    {
        "ID" : 3,
        "FromID" : 80,
        "ToID" : 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected output

```
ID    |    FromID    |    ToID    |
1     |     70       |     12     |
3     |     80       |     1      |
```

I used the below code to do the same in SQL Server. Is there any matching function to `OPENJSON` in MySQL.

```
DECLARE @Relationship AS TABLE(FromID INT,ToID INT,ID INT)
INSERT INTO @Relationship (FromID,ToID,ID)
SELECT FromID, ToID, ID
FROM OPENJSON(@RelationshipType)
WITH (FromID INT, ToID INT, ID INT)
```

Comment: Look at inserting the JSON document into a JSON data type column and then using JSON_TABLE to temporarily change the unstructured JSON data into a structured table.

Comment: What version of MySQL will be used?.

Comment: Thanks, @DaveStokes, Could you please provide any reference link or answer if you have

Comment: For an intro to JSON_TABLE() see https://elephantdolphin.blogspot.com/2019/05/structuring-your-unstructured-json-data.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example using [JSON_TABLE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html). I tested this on MySQL 8.0.16 in my sandbox environment.

```
mysql> create table relationship(id int primary key, fromid int, toid int);

mysql> insert into relationship select * from json_table(
'{ "RelationshipType" : [ { "ID" : 1, "FromID" : 70, "ToID" : 12 }, { "ID" : 3, "FromID" : 80, "ToID" : 1 } ] }',
'$.RelationshipType[*]' columns (
  id int path '$.ID',
  fromid int path '$.FromID',
  toid int path '$.ToID'
)) as j
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from relationship;
+----+--------+------+
| id | fromid | toid |
+----+--------+------+
|  1 |     70 |   12 |
|  3 |     80 |    1 |
+----+--------+------+
```

The JSON_TABLE() function requires MySQL 8.0.4 or later. It isn't implemented in earlier versions of MySQL.

Comment: Do you have any solution for this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57475029/logging-errors-within-the-exit-handler-in-mysql

Comment: That's a duplicate question, another user gave you a link, and I voted to close your question as a duplicate.